# String terminator issues

Tags: c

If I type in this code, it compiles and runs (I use GCC)

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{

char sentence[8]="September";

printf("The size of the array is %d \n",sizeof(sentence));

printf("The array is %s \n",sentence);
}
```

and gives the output

> The size of the array is 8
>
> > The array is Septembe

How is this working? A string terminator is needed for C to know that the string has ended. How is the array worth 8 bytes of space and knows where to stop?

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. It may work, or it may explode.

Comment: Which version of GCC, and with which options?  You should be getting a compulsory warning — all the C standards require that.  The compiler is allowed to compile non-compliant code, in any way it chooses.

Comment: compilator is adding terminator for you because your not allocating memory by hand

Comment: You just got lucky that there happened to be a zero byte in the next memory location. There's no requirement for this, and the compiler probably didn't do it intentionally.

Comment: @bboumend That is completely incorrect. `sentence` does *not* have room for a NUL terminator.

Comment: I vote you got lucky. Try declaring some more non-terminated array strings before and after, see what gets printed, eg Augus and Novemb.

Comment: Also, the correct printf format for a size_t (the result of the sizeof operator) is `%zu`, not `%d`. Another place where you "got lucky". (Although I always think that programs which do not blow up on UB are the result of bad luck, not good luck, since the effect is that you don't fix the bug before it has disastrous results.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By passing a non-NUL-terminated string to `printf("%s")`, you're invoking *undefined behavior*.

By its very nature, the result is undefined. It may seemingly "work" (like you're seeing).

---

As others have explained, what's probably happening is that there happens to be a zero byte after your string, which stops `printf` from going further. However, if you were to add more *stuff* around that variable, you'd probably see different behavior:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char sentence[8] = "September";        // NOT NUL TERMINATED!
    char stuff[] = "This way is better";

    printf("%s\n", sentence);              // Will overrun sentence
    return 0;
}
```